# How can i generate files with gulp?

Tags: gulp

I need a task for file generating. 
I know this one

```js
gulp.task("directories", function() {
    return gulp
        .src("*.*", { read: false })
        .pipe(??("./index.html")) <-------------------- 
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./css"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./scss"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./img"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./fonts"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./js"));
});
```

Comment: You want the plugin that will read your `html` files and get the links to the various resources in it like `css, img, etc.`?

Comment: No. I need a plugin that will be able to create files.

Comment: What do mean "create files"?  From what?

Comment: Just create a file. I want to see in my gulpfile script that will be generate folder and files in it. For example: css > style.css